# react-file-viewer : Display file from an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file

I'm trying to use `react-file-viewer` package to preview pdf files in my application. Can I use this package with an api that requests for a file from an external file storage source ?

App-a is a file storage application where I upload files.

App-b is the application in which I want to preview the uploaded files and where I plan to use `react-file-viewer`

```
import React from 'react'
import FileViewer from 'react-file-viewer';

const file_pdf = 'files/sample.pdf';
const type_pdf ='pdf';

export default class FilePreview extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="mWrapper">
                <div className="gWrapper">
                    <div className="dViewer">
                        <div className="gSubtitle">
                            <h2>DOCX</h2>
                        </div>
                        <FileViewer
                            fileType={type_doc}
                            filePath={file_doc}
                            />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Where `file_doc` here is a physical path to the directory within my application structure. Can this instead be an API call ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useEffect` hook to make a call to the api. When you get your data, you set the path and file type for the `FileViewer` component.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
....

export default class FilePreview extends React.Component {
const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  fetch('https://your.document/api/')
  .then(results => results.json())
  .then(data => {
    setFile(data.results);
  });
},[]);

render() {
    return (
        <div className="mWrapper">
            <div className="gWrapper">
                <div className="dViewer">
                    <div className="gSubtitle">
                        <h2>DOCX</h2>
                    </div>
                    {file &&
                      <FileViewer
                        fileType={file.type_doc}
                        filePath={file.file_doc}
                        />
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```